# Where is ADM in Android Studio 3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

Today i have upgraded from Android Studio 3.0 to 3.1 but I can´t find the [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html)!

[image]

[image]

How can access to the **[Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html)** in Android Studio 3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Android Studio 3.1 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#device_monitor_available_from_the_command_line):

> **Device Monitor available from the command line**
>
> In Android Studio 3.1, the Device Monitor serves less of a role than it previously did. In many cases, the functionality available through the Device Monitor is now provided by new and improved tools.
>
> See the [Device Monitor documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) for instructions for invoking the Device Monitor from the command line and for details of the tools available through the Device Monitor.

So you need to manually start it from the command line if you still want to run the Device Monitor. Otherwise, migrate to the [updated performance tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#performance_tools) and [updated Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#layout_inspector) built directly into Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i found that the only way is opening from the command line!

Looking for the SDK location folder `/tools` then execute `monitor`

[image]

but i found a problem, the AS must be closed because i receive that the port 8700 cannot be open because is used!

[image]

so to open ADM from command line now i have to close AS.

Device Monitor available from the command line

> In Android Studio 3.1, the Device Monitor serves less of a role than
>   it previously did. In many cases, the functionality available through
>   the Device Monitor is now provided by new and improved tools.

See the Device Monitor documentation for instructions for invoking the Device Monitor from the command line and for details of the tools available through the Device Monitor.

thanks for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525023/250260) @ianhanniballake now i see the info in the [official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#device_monitor_available_from_the_command_line)

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.1, the tools have changed. The DDMS or ADM tools were replaced by the Device File Explorer tool. You need to go to the menu. Follow these steps:

To open, click View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer.

[Here is a link for more tips](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#device_monitor_available_from_the_command_line). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Mihai Chelaru.

Comment: I'm sorry. Is AVD not ADM. Greets!